# Are there natural Dirichlet series whose completions have poles in the region of absolute convergence?

Tags: nt.number-theory, l-functions, dirichlet-series, selberg-class

The Selberg class of $L$-functions are Dirichlet series
$$ L(s, f) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a(n)}{n^s}, $$
satisfying certain properties that can be abbreviated as analyticity, a Ramanujan conjecture, a functional equation, and an Euler product.

In the functional equation: we suppose there are numbers $Q, \lambda_j, \mu_j$, and $\omega$ such that the gamma factor
$$\Delta(s) = Q^s \prod_{j = 1}^k \Gamma(\lambda_j s + \mu_j)$$
multiplied by the $L$-function $L(s, f)$ satisfies
$$ \Lambda(s, f) := L(s, f) \Delta(s) = \omega \overline{\Lambda(\overline{1-s}, f)}.$$
Further, the parameters in the functional equation are each restricted:

- $Q \in \mathbb{R}^+$,
- $\lambda_j \in \mathbb{R}^+$,
- $\mu_j \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\mathrm{Re} \, \mu_j \geq 0$, and
- $\omega$ satisfies $\lvert \omega \rvert = 1$.

Many of the $L$-functions I've studied are in the Selberg class. But I've also studied and used Dirichlet series associated to half-integral weight modular forms, which don't have an Euler product and whose functional equation doesn't reflect into itself. These half-integral weight Dirichlet series appear in arithmetic applications and thus seem natural to me.

> I wonder whether there are other natural Dirichlet series that are not quite in the Selberg class. In particular, I am currently thinking about the requirements on the parameters $\mu_j$. Are there examples of natural Dirichlet series with functional equation, and whose gamma factors in the functional equation have parameter $\mu_j$ with $\mathrm{Re} \, \mu_j < 0$?

> Or, more dramatically, is there a natural Dirichlet series with functional equation, normalized to converge absolutely in the half plane $\mathrm{Re}\,s > 1$, such that the "completed series" $L(s)\Delta(s)$ has a pole with $\mathrm{Re}\,s > 1$? This is equivalent to there being a gamma factor with $\mathrm{Re} (\mu_j / \lambda_j) \, < -1$.

I am guessing that the answer is *no*. So implicit in this question is the follow-up question of why such series would not be of non-artificial interest.

Comment: It would be better to write $\Delta(s)$ as $L_\infty(s)$: it is essentially the archimedean factor complementing all the Euler factors at primes. Writing $\Delta$ is not consistent with notation used in actual examples people use. Selberg's axioms were designed to cover all cases where GRH is expected to hold. That was their only original purpose. The axioms for the Selberg class are more abstract than real examples: in practice $\lambda_j$ is always 1 or $1/2$, and $\Gamma$-function identities show that in practice all actual examples can be written to have $\lambda_j = 1/2$ for all $j$.

Comment: You're probably right. I was coming at this just after having read the papers of Chandrasakharan and Narasimhan, and I used their $\Delta(s)$ notation.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Does $\zeta(s-1)$ count as "not quite in the Selberg class"?  It has a Dirichlet series with a functional equation, and the gamma factors have a $\mu_j$ with negative real part.  In particular, it has a simple pole at $s=2$.  It is not in the Selberg class because the Dirichlet coefficients $a(n)=n$ are too large.

Comment: I forgot whether the normalization condition $a_{1}=1$ is required in the definition of the Selberg class?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN I usually expect so, yes.